# Disabling clicks on a certain part of the page using div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using the following example as a client in my web browser to access my remote desktop using Guacamole project. But it gives full access of computer to the user.

Although I have used some VNC/RDP restrictions to apply limits from server side. But still the requirement is that user must not able to interact with some portions of the application on the remote computer from front end (like close or minimize button or portion of Top left or top right page) so he can only use the application but can not minimize or close it.

So I was thinking that maybe I could disable click on these portions so it will not be transferred to the remote desktop.

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="guacamole.css"/>
    <title>Guacamole</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Display -->
    <div id="display"></div>

    <!-- Guacamole JavaScript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="guacamole-common-js/all.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Init -->
    <script type="text/javascript"> /* <![CDATA[ */
        // Get display div from document
        var display = document.getElementById("display");
        // Instantiate client, using an HTTP tunnel for communications.
        var guac = new Guacamole.Client(
            new Guacamole.HTTPTunnel("tunnel")
        );
        // Add client to display div
        display.appendChild(guac.getDisplay().getElement());

        // Error handler
        guac.onerror = function(error) {
            alert(error);
        };
        // Connect
        guac.connect();
        // Disconnect on close
        window.onunload = function() {
            guac.disconnect();
        }
        // Mouse
        var mouse = new Guacamole.Mouse(guac.getDisplay().getElement());
        mouse.onmousedown = 
        mouse.onmouseup   =
        mouse.onmousemove = function(mouseState) {
            guac.sendMouseState(mouseState);
        };
        // Keyboard
        var keyboard = new Guacamole.Keyboard(document);
        keyboard.onkeydown = function (keysym) {
            guac.sendKeyEvent(1, keysym);
        };
        keyboard.onkeyup = function (keysym) {
            guac.sendKeyEvent(0, keysym);
        };
    /* ]]> */ </script>

</body>
```

What I get on the front end is the complete picture of my remote computer. Any idea how to limit the interaction from front end?

Comment: I would highly discourage you from doing that. Even if you can disable click on some parts of the application, the user will still be able to use keyboard commands. In the worst case the application could crash and the client would have the full desktop available afterwards. Could could explain what kind of application you are trying to publish? Maybe there is a better way already implemented.

Comment: I want the users to evaluate different desktop applications (can be of different domains). For that purpose, I want to share my remote desktop with them through a web browser (Currently using guacamole server/client to share desktop using a web browser and Rdp/VNC server). But as remote desktop give full access to the user so I want to limit their access to a single application and they should also not be able to close the application.

Comment: I was thinking of disabling the top portion of my page(where the minimize and close button) so thought the mouse click will not be transferred to the server. I tried TightVNC to apply some restrictions but I need more features

Comment: If the user should be able to evaluate an application, I would recommend to set up a virtual machine. The client connects to the virtual machine and when he's done, you can reset the machine to a snapshot made before he connected. So no matter what the user does, the machine will be save. Also you can heavily limit the access rights inside of the virtual machine.